# windows mobile put call on hold programmatically

Tags: c#, c++, windows-mobile, telephony

I need  to put on hold calls programmatically on windows mobile device. Other  operations as answering or rejecting call I accomplish simulating key presses.

Using the user interface of the phone, first I have to answer the phone, then put it on hold.

Is there any way to do this programmatically preferably in c# (or c++ if no option in c#)?

Thanks,

Comment: I should mention that I manage to detect a call and then I need to put it on hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [RIL_ManageCalls()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa917997.aspx) with the [RIL_CALLCMD_HOLDACTIVE_ACCEPTHELD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa919204.aspx) will do that. You will need to use P/Invoke to do this in C#.

If you prefer TAPI, then try [lineHold](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922008.aspx).

-PaulH

Comment: thanks again, I found C# OpenNETCF.Telephony wrapper over C++ TAPI which contains lineHold managed.